# Android Studio edittext is empty

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

When i want to get my text

```
var edittext1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
var text = edittext1.text.toString()
```

Then the string is always empty

Comment: Is it possible you are accessing the text too early (before any text has been added)? Make sure you are calling edittext1.text.toString() right at the moment you want to get your text from the editText

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have a synthetic import of your activity: e.g :

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic...
```

If you do, it might seem like the activity is confused between the variable name and id of the field. If you have the synthetic import, you don't need the `findViewById`,

You can just say something like `val edtText = edittext1.text.toString()`